# Android SQLite copy values from table to another table

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to copy some data in a table and insert into another table. I entered the data into an ArrayList, however, is only copied a given and not all those present. What am I missing?

```
private void Tras() {
String numero_ricevuto = (i.getStringExtra("numero"));
SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
final ArrayList<Dettaglio_i> dettaglii = new ArrayList<Dettaglio_i>();
 String sql = "SELECT data, unita_di_misura FROM prev WHERE numero = '"+numero_ricevuto+"'";
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
while (c.moveToNext()){
            Dettaglio_i e = new Dettaglio_i();
            e.data_ = c.getString(0);               
            e.unita_di_misura = c.getString(1);
            dettaglii.add(e);       
        }
c.close();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
Dettaglio_i e = new Dettaglio_i();
cv.put(VerTable.SI_NO, "0");
cv.put(VerTable .DATA, e.data_);
cv.put(VerTable .U_M, e.unita_di_misura);
boolean inserite = false;
            if (!inserite){
                long result = db.insert(VerTable .TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

                if (result > 0){
                    inserite = true;
                }
            }

            if (inserite){


            }
            db.close();

}
```

Comment: What exactly do the words "a given" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your code with this:

```
private void Tras() {
    String numero_ricevuto = (i.getStringExtra("numero"));
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String insert = String.format("INSERT INTO %s (%s, %s, %s) ",
            VerTable.TABLE_NAME, VerTable.SI_NO, VerTable.DATA, VerTable .U_M);

    String select = "SELECT '0', data, unita_di_misura FROM prev WHERE " +
            "numero='"+numero_ricevuto+"'";

    db.rawQuery(insert+select, null);

    db.close();
}
```